# Creating map label in ArcMap with information from 3 fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, sql

How do I create a map label in ArcMap 8 with information from 3 fields?

I want a label to contains information from the following fields: `Label`, `Land_Use`, `Acres`.  I want 3 line label.

Top line has the word "Field" followed by the data from the [label] field.
Line 2 will just have the data from the [land_use] field.
Line 3 will have the data from the [Acres] field followed by the word "acres".

Example:
Field 01
Pasture
10 acres

I think I need a "SQL" statement to put in the label manager.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Please confirm you are using ArcMap v8, a version that was released about 20 years ago?

Comment: ArcMap 8?  Really?  Are you running it on an NT machine?

Comment: Search the help for whatever version you are using with the term “stacked label”.

Answer (score 2):

In the label expression:

```vb
"Field " & [Label] & vbnewline & [Land_Use]  & vbnewline & [Acres]  & " acres"
```

[image]

[image]

I'm guessing that you possibly mean ArcMap 10.8 (rather than ArcMap 8), however I believe this should work in both versions (that said I don't have access to ArcMap 8 anymore so I can't test).